# macOS dynamic linker reports it loaded library which doesn't exist

Tags: java, macos, dyld

When running `java` with `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=TRUE` the following lines are contained in the output:

```
dyld[15078]: <C77B7FE3-7104-362A-B686-168971378ADC> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/A/JavaNativeFoundation
dyld[15078]: <BE429D77-6080-3D27-B4EE-12EE022386B4> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaRuntimeSupport.framework/Versions/A/JavaRuntimeSupport
```

However the repsecitve folders don't actually contain any binary files to load. For example this is the directory structure of `JavaNativeFoundation.framework`:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaNativeFoundation.framework
├── Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
└── Versions
    ├── A
    │   ├── Resources
    │   │   ├── BridgeSupport
    │   │   │   └── JavaNativeFoundation.bridgesupport
    │   │   ├── Info.plist
    │   │   └── version.plist
    │   └── _CodeSignature
    │       └── CodeResources
    └── Current -> A

7 directories, 4 files
```

Loading a dynamic library which links against the framework `JavaNativeFoundation` in the java program fails as expected:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: <path to the library>: dlopen(<path to the library>, 0x0001): Library not loaded: @rpath/JavaNativeFoundation
  Referenced from: <path to the library>
  Reason: tried: 
  '/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/Current/JavaNativeFoundation' (no such file), 
  '/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/Current/JavaNativeFoundation' (no such file), 
  '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk8u232-b09/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/./JavaNativeFoundation' (no such file),
  '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk8u232-b09/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/../JavaNativeFoundation' (no such file), 
  '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk8u232-b09/Contents/Home/bin
```

Note that `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/Current/` is a symlink to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/A/` so both logs actually refer to the same file. For me this looks like a contradiction. How can the dynamic linker load and not load
`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/[Current/A]/JavaNativeFoundation` at the same time.

I don't believe this to be specific to Java at all. It's just the context in which this pops up.

Some information regarding the OS (all mentioned machines are `Intel x86-64` based):

- The above scenario is for `macOS 12.1`
- The binary for `JavaNativeFoundation` is also missing on `macOS 11.5.2`
- On a different machine running `10.15.7` it exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to:

> New in macOS Big Sur 11 beta, the system ships with a built-in dynamic linker cache of all system-provided libraries. As part of this change, copies of dynamic libraries are no longer present on the filesystem. Code that attempts to check for dynamic library presence by looking for a file at a path or enumerating a directory will fail. Instead, check for library presence by attempting to dlopen() the path, which will correctly check for the library in the cache.

Apparently this also affects the dynamic linker itself while resolving transitive dependencies of a library. If the load command contains an absolute path it resolves it correctly. It’s only in the case that the path contains `@rpath` entries that the linker will check for the existence of the path (after substitution) and ignored the linker cache.